# WPF Spell checker not working on few laptops

Tags: c#, wpf

We have been using WPF spell-checker textbox for longtime. It never had any problem, but now few users started complaining that spell checker not working on their **new Window 10** laptop. All the wrong spellings are NOT highlighted with the red line below as it does normally. They located in UK and their machine **culture is Engligh UK**. However, most of our laptops are configured with same OS and culture and spell checker works perfectly fine.

When we tried to install language pack on their machine it showed that it's installed already as Windows 10 comes with .NET framework. We are struck here as what needs to be checked. It would be very helpful if someone can throw some lights on this.

Thanks

Comment: We found that it works fine if English (US) is added to the language. But most of our clients have only English (UK) added in their local machine. It would be very helpful if anyone help us on this..Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the `Language` property of the TextBox?

Comment: We are not setting language property of the TextBox. Hence, local machine settings should apply automatically. I was telling about machine language. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We've just had a very similar situation: Lots of people already have Windows 10 machines with "English (UK)" language installed, and a WPF application where the UK-English spell check has been working fine. Then a large number of users have been given new hardware, and the spell check was not working on the new machines for exactly the same application.

Go to the Windows button, press the "Settings" cog icon, type "Language Settings" and pick that item. The list of languages should contain "English (United Kingdom)", and ensure that it is the top of the list. If you change anything here, you may want to reboot to ensure the new settings are picked up. Failing that...

From an Administrator Powershell, use the following command...

```
Get-WindowsCapability -online >C:\list.txt
```

...to store the currently installed "Features on Demand" in the file "C:\list.txt". Within that file, we found...

```
Name : Language.Basic~~~en-GB~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

...whereas on the machines where the spell check was working, that feature's State was "Installed".

Here is the link to Microsoft's information about [Adding or removing Features on Demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities?view=windows-10#adding-or-removing-features-on-demand).